# how to find min and max of float number in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

The `min` and `max` functions in MATLAB work on only integer values. How can I find the **min** and **max** of a double vector?

```
a = [2.1 3.4 5.6 7.6]
min(a)
```

returns to me:

`Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've assigned `min` as a variable name for an array somewhere in your code.

When you call `min(a)`, MATLAB is trying to grab the indices `[2.1,3.4,5.6,7.6]` from your array `min`. To fix this problem, simply call the variable something else.

**EDIT:** And if you're running it outside of a function, clear `min` and `max`, as @Acorbe points out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear `min` and `max` since they are assigned already and their variable counterparts hide the function names.

To use them as functions, do first

```
 clear min
 clear max
```